# How to resolve importing library

Tags: tensorflow, keras, import

I am working on deep learning and when I run a code cell in Anaconda's jupyter Lab, I get the following error.
My environment is as follows.

environment

```
python 3.10.9
CuDA 12.1
numpy 1.23.5
keras 2.10
tensorflow 2.12.0
scikit 1.2.1
pillow 9.4.0
```

library

```py
import numpy as np
import os 
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

error

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 3
      1 import numpy as np
      2 import os 
----> 3 from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
      4 from PIL import Image
      5 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py:21
     15 """Implementation of the Keras API, the high-level API of TensorFlow.
     16 
     17 Detailed documentation and user guides are available at
     18 [keras.io](https://keras.io).
     19 """
     20 from keras import distribute
---> 21 from keras import models
     22 from keras.engine.input_layer import Input
     23 from keras.engine.sequential import Sequential

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models\__init__.py:18
      1 # Copyright 2022 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
      2 #
      3 # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   (...)
     13 # limitations under the License.
     14 # ==============================================================================
     15 """Keras models API."""
---> 18 from keras.engine.functional import Functional
     19 from keras.engine.sequential import Sequential
     20 from keras.engine.training import Model

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\dtensor\layout_map.py:27
     25 from keras.dtensor import lazy_variable
     26 from keras.dtensor import utils
---> 27 from keras.engine import base_layer
     29 # isort: off
     30 from tensorflow.python.util.deprecation import deprecated

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\saved_model\save_impl.py:34
     32 from keras.saving import saving_utils
     33 from keras.saving.saved_model import constants
---> 34 from keras.saving.saved_model import load as keras_load
     35 from keras.saving.saved_model import serialized_attributes
     36 from keras.saving.saved_model import utils

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py:29
     27 from keras.engine import input_spec
     28 from keras.optimizers.optimizer_v2 import optimizer_v2
---> 29 from keras.protobuf import saved_metadata_pb2
     30 from keras.protobuf import versions_pb2
     31 from keras.saving import saving_utils

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\protobuf\saved_metadata_pb2.py:16
     11 # @@protoc_insertion_point(imports)
     13 _sym_db = _symbol_database.Default()
---> 16 from keras.protobuf import versions_pb2 as keras_dot_protobuf_dot_versions__pb2
     19 DESCRIPTOR = _descriptor.FileDescriptor(
     20   name='keras/protobuf/saved_metadata.proto',
     21   package='third_party.py.keras.protobuf',
   (...)
     25   ,
     26   dependencies=[keras_dot_protobuf_dot_versions__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,])
     31 _SAVEDMETADATA = _descriptor.Descriptor(
     32   name='SavedMetadata',
     33   full_name='third_party.py.keras.protobuf.SavedMetadata',
   (...)
     58   serialized_end=175,
     59 )

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\protobuf\versions_pb2.py:36
     13 _sym_db = _symbol_database.Default()
     18 DESCRIPTOR = _descriptor.FileDescriptor(
     19   name='keras/protobuf/versions.proto',
     20   package='third_party.py.keras.protobuf',
   (...)
     23   serialized_pb=_b('\n\x1dkeras/protobuf/versions.proto\x12\x1dthird_party.py.keras.protobuf\"K\n\nVersionDef\x12\x10\n\x08producer\x18\x01 \x01(\x05\x12\x14\n\x0cmin_consumer\x18\x02 \x01(\x05\x12\x15\n\rbad_consumers\x18\x03 \x03(\x05\x62\x06proto3')
     24 )
     29 _VERSIONDEF = _descriptor.Descriptor(
     30   name='VersionDef',
     31   full_name='third_party.py.keras.protobuf.VersionDef',
     32   filename=None,
     33   file=DESCRIPTOR,
     34   containing_type=None,
     35   fields=[
---> 36     _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
     37       name='producer', full_name='third_party.py.keras.protobuf.VersionDef.producer', index=0,
     38       number=1, type=5, cpp_type=1, label=1,
     39       has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
     40       message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
     41       is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
     42       serialized_options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
     43     _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
     44       name='min_consumer', full_name='third_party.py.keras.protobuf.VersionDef.min_consumer', index=1,
     45       number=2, type=5, cpp_type=1, label=1,
     46       has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
     47       message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
     48       is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
     49       serialized_options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
     50     _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
     51       name='bad_consumers', full_name='third_party.py.keras.protobuf.VersionDef.bad_consumers', index=2,
     52       number=3, type=5, cpp_type=1, label=3,
     53       has_default_value=False, default_value=[],
     54       message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
     55       is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
     56       serialized_options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
     57   ],
     58   extensions=[
     59   ],
     60   nested_types=[],
     61   enum_types=[
     62   ],
     63   serialized_options=None,
     64   is_extendable=False,
     65   syntax='proto3',
     66   extension_ranges=[],
     67   oneofs=[
     68   ],
     69   serialized_start=64,
     70   serialized_end=139,
     71 )
     73 DESCRIPTOR.message_types_by_name['VersionDef'] = _VERSIONDEF
     74 _sym_db.RegisterFileDescriptor(DESCRIPTOR)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py:561, in FieldDescriptor.__new__(cls, name, full_name, index, number, type, cpp_type, label, default_value, message_type, enum_type, containing_type, is_extension, extension_scope, options, serialized_options, has_default_value, containing_oneof, json_name, file, create_key)
    555 def __new__(cls, name, full_name, index, number, type, cpp_type, label,
    556             default_value, message_type, enum_type, containing_type,
    557             is_extension, extension_scope, options=None,
    558             serialized_options=None,
    559             has_default_value=True, containing_oneof=None, json_name=None,
    560             file=None, create_key=None):  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
--> 561   _message.Message._CheckCalledFromGeneratedFile()
    562   if is_extension:
    563     return _message.default_pool.FindExtensionByName(full_name)

TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly.
If this call came from a _pb2.py file, your generated code is out of date and must be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0.
If you cannot immediately regenerate your protos, some other possible workarounds are:
 1. Downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower.
 2. Set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python (but this will use pure-Python parsing and will be much slower).
```

How to resolve this error? Please explain to me in a way that a beginner can understand.

Comment: there is a mismatch between the protobuf package and the TensorFlow version you are using, try updating protobuf  package using `pip install --upgrade protobuf ` or downgrade tensoflow
`

Comment: I changed python to 3.7, tensorflow version to 1.13.1 and keras version to 2.2.4, which solved the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the protobuf mismatch error which can be resolved by installing required **protobuf version 3.20** as stated in the error

```
pip install protobuf==3.20
```

Also please import keras from tensorflow as below:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
```